# Emmet with styled components autocompletion

Tags: jsx, styled-components, emmet

Im used to emmet autocompleting
things like
df = display flex
tac = text align center

now when I type this inside style components I have to type it very fast otherwise emmet recognises
df as dfn

and

tac as touch-action

how can I configure it so it doesnt do change its behaviour in jsx ?

Comment: I was unable to fix this ... I disabled quick suggestions for now .. and toggle it with ctrl+space .... even though i have 
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"

it doest work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VsCode extension named "vscode-styled-components" can be used for this purpose.